# Is it secure to run PHP under main limited user instead of www-data?

Tags: php, linux, security

I found one guide to setup nginx for ubuntu where php executing user were changed from www-data to home user, so i'm little confused, is it secure to do something like that?
It's solving a lot of problems like wrong file permission or impossibility to upload files from filezilla via ssh, but idk, wouldn't it bring security problems with running php all sites from home dir?

Answer (score 1):

The www-data is a native user for linux operation systems used for web services. If you change it from another user you could transform into something more or less secuire - it all depends on how the permissions of this user are going to be configured.

Something that some tutorials tell you to do is to create a new user and remove permissions like:

- Read permission from `/etc/passwd` (www-data user has this permission)
- Read/Write permission from `/tmp` (every user has this permission)

But it's not a necessary change. Like I said, it will be more or less secure. It all depends on the permission level of this user.